# Sources for meterological data with high resolution

Tags: data, layers, climate, maxent

I was running **Maxent** on an endemic species of andaman and nicobar.But the climate data
I have from [worlclim.org](http://www.worldclim.org/tiles.php) ( tile number 29 ) is not of high resolution and thus I can't see the distribution clearly.Can anyone please suggest me where i could get environment data for
andaman and nicobar islands of high resolution.
The middle left hand side with purple dots is the andaman nicobar.

The current resolution is **1km** and i want better one like **10 m** or so , so that I can see small landmasses also with detail and clarity.

[image]

Comment: Could you state what you mean by 'high resolution'?

Comment: I want to see the andaman nicobar islands clearly , a big image so that distribution across it can be seen clearly

Comment: @Rob Lodge hope I made myself clear

Comment: As in, what is the resolution of your current data? What resolution do you require? 10 m, 50 m, 100 m, 1 km, 10 km etc... If you include this in your original question it will help others to provide the best possible answer for you.

Comment: @RobLodge I downloaded the data from here http://www.worldclim.org/tiles.php  ( tile number 29) which has 1km and I want a better resolution so that even small landmasses can be seen with clearity

Comment: As always keep in mind that very high resolution data is simply not free / easy to generate. You might consider that. What you could do: Downscale/interpolate your data to a smaller scale (this is what Hjimans et al. have done with Worldclim anyway). Look for regional meterological stations and generate your own climate predictors.

Comment: Downscaled climate sounds like false precision to me. How many climate stations are there on these islands in the original data? I think you are better off trying to find high resolution landcover data (20-30m) to refine your models.

Comment: @Curlew so from where can I get the high resolution data even if it is paid version.

Comment: I don't know as i am not an expert on indian meterological services and i also don't want to advertise commercial products. Just google around, look which data other studies used and so on. My best guess would be to look for any meterological stations on these islands and generate your own data from their records. And by the way: You didn't really specify what data you need.

Comment: @Curlew i needed data like annual precipitation , altitude,mean temperature, etc

Comment: Annual precipitation or mean temperature on 10 metre scale is false precision.